# Difficulties finding location and scale parameters from PDF

Tags: density-function, lognormal-distribution

I am having difficulty finding the correct location and scale parameters for a PDF diagram that I need to validate my data. [image: Bubble size distribution]
I have already calculated the location parameter to be -1.01, but I am unsure about the scale parameter.
I would appreciate any guidance or correction you could provide.
I am currently conducting a simulation that involves population balance modeling to analyze particle size distribution. In my research, I have found that most of the reference papers describe the size distribution using a PDF diagram that appears to resemble a log-normal distribution, given its skewed nature to the right.
This diagram is not mine, but it belongs to Huang, 2019 and I am trying to run a simulation in order to obtain the same results as shown in the diagram.
I have previously attempted to adjust the location and scale parameter values that I obtained from the graph, but the results I obtained were always different from the graph. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Is it a Gamma distribution that you are fitting on your data? Then there are different parameter estimation methods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Parameter_estimation

Comment: You have included the lognormal tag, do you *know* the distribution is lognormal? In general, the plot you provided isn't enough in isolation to tell you anything (parametrically speaking).

Comment: Did you notice the area under your curve is much smaller than $1$?  (After all, the entire area beneath it lies within a rectangle of width less than $1$ and height less than $0.5.$)  Thus, it cannot possibly be a correct representation of any PDF.  Perhaps you could explain how you obtained this diagram, then, and how it might be related to your data?

Comment: The duplicate explains how to estimate lognormal parameters from binned data like these.  It will give you excellent estimates for these data, assuming the distribution really is close to lognormal.

Comment: @whuber My interpretation of the question was that there is a fixed distribution and that the plot is created from that fixed distribution. Therefore, given two parameters, pick any two bars to use for the probability lying in that interval. The $(\mu,\sigma)$ should be identical irrespective of the bars used. Not sure it this characterisation is distinct from the linked duplicate. What do you think?

Comment: @statsplease I believe it more likely that this is trying to be a bar plot of relative frequencies of binned observations and that the curve was fit to the bar heights.  Although the estimates might vary little or not at all depending on the total count, the *standard errors* of the parameter estimates will depend on the bin counts.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, just worth pointing out that is a terrible plot. The labelling on the y-axis is completely disingenuous and outright wrong. The smooth density (lognormal apparently) shown is surely some scaled version of the density. We know this because how could the density shown sum to 1 across its support?

The histogram bars seem to represent the probability mass for intervals incrementing by 0.1 from 0 to 1. Nothing is shown for (0, 0.1]* for some reason.

In any case, we can ignore the density and simply utilize the histogram bars to solve for the parameters of the distribution. Take any two bars. Accurately(?) read off the probability masses occurring in those interval. Also note the intervals themselves. If we define the masses as
$$(m_{1},m_{2})$$
and the corresponding two intervals as
$$(a_{1},b_{1})\quad\text{and}\quad(a_{2},b_{2})$$
and further define
$$G(\mu, \sigma;a,b)=F(b;\mu,\sigma)-F(a;\mu,\sigma)$$
where $F(x;\mu, \sigma)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a lognormal distribution.

Your problem reduces to solving the system of equations
$$\begin{align}
G(\mu, \sigma;a_{1},b_{1})=m_{1}\\
G(\mu, \sigma;a_{2},b_{2})=m_{2}
\end{align}$$
for $(\mu, \sigma)$.

In any case, this is what I replicated:

[image]

giving $(\mu, \sigma)=(-1.2950867,0.3694235)$. Of course your exact results will depend on the values you read off the plot.

---

- Or is it [0, 0.1) or (0, 0.1) or [0, 0.1]? Who knows.

Comment: I also suspected that it was not possible to obtain a certain value. I would like to know how to scale down. Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: @AgisFitrony Can I ask how you know what distribution (lognormal) it is? Was it specified in the paper? And further how did you determine the location parameter? I saw your edit to the question where you seem to indicate that the lognormal distribution was a guess. There are many right-skewed distributions so observing the shape probably doesn't help much.

Comment: Also, you state you already know the location parameter is -1.01. How did you obtain this? I can't seem to find a $\sigma$ that gives the above plot for a $\text{LN}(\mu=-1.01,\sigma)$.

Comment: The paper did not specify the distribution. I determined it by extracting the data using WebPlot and performing calculations based on the explanation provided in this website towardsdatascience.com/…. While I did manage to find the scale parameter, the result was different from my reference graph and how can I solve the equations you provided? I am not sure if it is possible to solve them manually. Do I need to use software to solve them?

Comment: @AgisFitrony How did you solve for the one parameter (independently from the other parameter) only visually without using software?

Comment: I apologize if my previous statement was unclear. I was actually using WebPlot and Excel to determine the parameters. Is it acceptable to use these tools for this purpose?

Comment: My issue was that I didn't understand how you independently solved or one of the parameters without considering the other? They have to be solved jointly together.

Comment: I did manage to find the scale parameter using the method I mentioned earlier, but when I tried to plot the distribution, it appeared different from the reference graph. Therefore, I am wondering if there are other solutions or a more accurate way to determine the parameters.

Comment: What method was that? 'Webplot and Excel' isn't a statistical method.

Comment: That is correct, as I am new to statistics, I may need to learn more about probability diagrams. I appreciate your suggestions and inputs, but I don't think this conversation will be getting us anywhere. Therefore, I will continue to study and learn more about this topic. Thank you.